# Android App to Stream IP Camera using P2P mode over Mobile port?

Tags: android, camera, video-streaming, video-processing, ip-camera

I am trying to stream the video via IP camera on an Android App. I have been successful to get the video using the following:

1. RTSP using Media Player and Surface View.
2. RTSP using Video View.
3. Redirecting to VLC for streaming the video.
4. Redirecting to Native
5. Video Player for streaming the video.

Now, all these cases are working but with a lag of 7-8 seconds on average even over the local network.

I see some apps that steam without any lag even on remote network, that use **mobile port (18600)**. This port is normally associated with P2P mode on a camera.(This assumption is purely based on my understanding as per the following settings available on my camera set up interface, which shows: Mode- P2P, Port - 18600, RealTime - Normal).

Can someone help me understand how we can connect to mobile port of the IP camera on P2P mode? and How this mode does not show lag where as RTSP does?

Thanks in advance.