# How to connect to P2P Camera

Tags: android, camera, p2p, ip-camera

I've bought an IP Camera with P2P capabilities and I've been struggling on how this works.
On the bottom of my camera there is an ID which I put on an Android application and it'll just work, it doesn't matter if its behind a router.
Now I've been trying to replicate this with coding but I have no idea where to start. I found this
[Android App to Stream IP Camera using P2P mode over Mobile port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049699/android-app-to-stream-ip-camera-using-p2p-mode-over-mobile-port)
Which is what I'm trying to do but still I'm lost as of how this works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Same question here. Did you find any solution?